# Take a string as input and returns valid if it is composed entirely of the characters A, T, C, and G in Java

Tags: java, string, character

So, I have this class that takes a string as an argument and returns valid if it is only composed of the characters A, T, C, and G. This is what I have so far.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char chr = s.charAt(i);
            if(chr != 'A' || chr != 'C' || chr != 'T' || chr != 'G') {
                System.out.println("invalid");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("valid");
        }
    }
}
```

It is returning invalid for everything when CTGATCG should return valid and DGHAIS should return invalid. 
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: **Every** character is always not equal to at least one of A,C,T and G.  I think you meant to write `chr != 'A' && chr != 'C' ...`

Comment: Also, you can't say the string is valid before all the chars have been checked.

Comment: Please read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your if-statement from:

```
if(chr != 'A' || chr != 'C' || chr != 'T' || chr != 'G') {
```

to

```
if(chr != 'A' && chr != 'C' && chr != 'T' && chr != 'G') {
```

Each char is not equal to either `A` or `C` or the other ones. In your current version, you are basically excluding everything.

Furthermore, you would print "valid" for every char in your input.

The correct code should look like this:

```
String s = args[0];
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char chr = s.charAt(i);
    if(chr != 'A' && chr != 'C' && chr != 'T' && chr != 'G') {
        System.out.println("invalid");
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("valid");
```

If you want to do more stuff in your program, you should use a boolean variable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        if(!s.matches("[ACGT]+")
            System.out.println("invalid");
        else
            System.out.println("valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that code. 1 line is all you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0].matches("[ACGT]*") ? "valid" : "invalid");
}
```

This code will perform pretty well too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use || (OR) in this case, you should use && (AND).

Your condition now means "If the character is not A,C,T,G at the same, it is invalid".